# How to get geolocation then auto submit form without having to click a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

I want to call a page to get geolocation, then auto submit form to my php page to `$_REQUEST` `getlat` and `getlon` without clicking a submit button.  Here is what I have.  In my browser inspector I see my geolocation values, but it will not auto submit.  I tried using the `onload` function in my body tag, but then found you can only call one function at a time, also I read this is a bad practice anyway. I have view another similar questions but cant piece it together. Thanks for any help

```
<html>
    <script>
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    showPosition,
                    positionError
                );
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('getlat').value = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById('getlon').value = position.coords.longitude;
            lon = document.getElementById('getlon').value;
            lat = document.getElementById('getlat').value;
        }

        function positionError(error) {
            if (error.PERMISSION_DENIED) alert('Please accept geolocation');
            hideLoadingDiv();
            showError(
                'Geolocation is not enabled. Please enable to use this feature'
            );
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function PageLoad() {
            getLocation();
            document.frm1.submit();
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <script>
            window.onload = PageLoad();
        </script>

        <form action="results.php" name="frm1">
            <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="getlon" />
            <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="getlat" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be unaware of the asynchronous nature of javascript otherwise it's a very simple problem. Anyway here I explain

When page loads and it finds `window.onload=PageLoad();` it calls the `PageLoad()` function and then

```
function PageLoad() {
    getLocation(); // <-- gets called
    document.frm1.submit(); // <-- doesn't wait for getLocation() to complete; 
                            // rather runs right away
}
```

As you can guess, while `getLocation()` is doing it's job (in sorta "thread" A) `document.frm1.submit();` gets run (in another sorta "thread" B) and submits the form which isn't what you expect.

So what you need to do instead is move the submit related code in the `showPosition()` so once browser gets the location and then form is submitted.

```
function showPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById("getlat").value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById("getlon").value = position.coords.longitude;
    lon=document.getElementById("getlon").value;
    lat=document.getElementById("getlat").value;
    document.frm1.submit(); <-- submits when browser gets the users location
}
```

Comment: Perfect, and thanks for the explanation.  FYI it didn't work at first, then I noticed I forgot to add method="post" in my <form> tag.  Once I did that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

According [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Getting_the_current_position) documentation

> getCurrentPosition() method. This initiates an asynchronous request to
>   detect the user's position

You are sending the form before obtaining the coordinates. The solution is to send this form with the value of the updated hidden inputs just when the asynchronous request ends. Please try the following example

Having this html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="results.php" name="frm1">
            <input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="getlon" />
            <input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="getlat" />
        </form>
        <script src="geo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    pageLoad();
});

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError);
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    console.log(position);
    document.getElementById('getlat').value = position.coords.latitude;
    document.getElementById('getlon').value = position.coords.longitude;
    lon = document.getElementById('getlon').value;
    lat = document.getElementById('getlat').value;

    document.frm1.submit(); // here the form is submit
}

function positionError(error) {
    if (error.PERMISSION_DENIED) alert('Please accept geolocation');
    hideLoadingDiv();
    showError('Geolocation is not enabled. Please enable to use this feature');
}

function pageLoad() {
    getLocation();
}
```

Here I ma using when DOM is ready